# Cannot run jersey sample projects

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

I downloaded the jersey repo from github and I am trying to run the example projects, specifically `examples/oauth2-client-google-webapp`. When I run `mmvn clean package jetty:run`, I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR]   The project org.glassfish.jersey.examples:oauth2-client-google-webapp:2.26-SNAPSHOT
       (/home/user/test/jersey/examples/oauth2-client-google-webapp/pom.xml) 
        has 4 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:pom:2.26-SNAPSHOT 
     in https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases was cached in the 
     local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of java.net-releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.glassfish.jersey.examples:project:2.26-SNAPSHOT, /home/user/test/jersey/examples/pom.xml, line 136, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for 
    org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet:jar is 
    missing. @ line 82, column 21
[ERROR]'dependencies.dependency.version' for 
    org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-bean-validation:jar 
    is missing. @ line 86, column 21
[ERROR]'dependencies.dependency.version' for
     org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-mustache:jar is missing.
     @ line 90, column 21
```

What could be the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Try to update project using `force update to lastest snapshoot` option in eclipse

Comment: @TuyenNguyen is there a way to do this on command line? I have already pulled the latest git repo

Comment: You can try this: `mvn clean install -U`